# Turn off SSL to Google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

How would I go about turning off SSL when sending data to Google cloud storage?  I'm using their `apiclient` module.

The data that I'm putting to the cloud is already encrypted.  I'm also trying to put data from AWS to GCS in 512k sized blocks.  I'm seeing about 600ms+ in putting just one block.  I was thinking if I don't have to set up a secure connection then I can cut down that PUT time a little.

The code is server side code that lives on AWS and for some god awful reason my company wants to have two (S3 and GCS) as production storage regions.

Comment: Why would you ever want to disable SSL?

Comment: As an alternative, you may want to try using gsutil with the "-m" option (enables multithreading) to move the data. "gsutil -m cp s3://bucket/* gs://bucket/" will do what you want fairly efficiently. https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: "The data that I'm putting to the cloud is already encrypted" - how? Just because it is encrypted doesn't mean it is safe. Furthermore, once the secure connection is set up, the encryption and decryption is quick due to the use of symmetric keys rather than asymetrical keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apiclient uses the Google Cloud Storage JSON API, which requires HTTPS.

Can you say a bit about why you would like to disable SSL?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've updated my quest to explain why I would want this.

Comment: Jeff - the JSON API requires HTTPS in part because it uses OAuth2 for authorization, which is dependent on session security to transmit the bearer tokens. Using OAuth2 without HTTPS is not secure.

Answer (score 3):

Try to PUT in larger blocks, since latency is probably the gating factor.  You can edit the DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE in apiclient/http.py as a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of changing the block sizes. The key that's in S3 (which is also encrypted) needs to mirror the key in GCS.

Comment: Do you mean the data itself is distributed across many 512KB files?

Comment: Yes petabytes of 512KB files

Comment: See Brandon's comment on using gsutil -m, then.  It will allow you to parallelize this operation.  With prefix matching, you can even parallelize across multiple machines.

Comment: Also, if you have petabytes of data to transfer, it is worth emailing gs-team@google.com to see if you can get additional pointers or support.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep SSL. When using OAuth2 (as GCS does), any request may include an http header (access_token) that you don't want third parties to see. Otherwise, hijacking your account would be extremely easy.